# Eloquent where-()-firstOrFail() doesn't return attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4.1.  I have a table `profiles` and an class Profiles that extends Eloquent with protected $table = 'profiles'.  There's a row in the table with id = 1 and first_name = 'Admin'.  I have the following code:

```
$profile->where('id','=',1)->firstOrFail();
```

I'm not getting any failure but nor am I getting any of the table attributes.  $profile->first_name is null.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

when you use **where()** method use it with model like this

```
$profile = Profile::where('id','=',1)->firstOrFail();
```

or

```
$profile = Profile::where('id',1)->firstOrFail();
```

**OR**

use `findOrFail()` method if you need to search with id

```
$profile = Profile::findOrFail(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` or `findOrFail` method, which searches by `id` columns on it's own.

```
$profile->findOrFail($id);

// or using Facade

Profile::findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid newbie!  I wasn't using the static methods, but rather trying to use the methods on an instantiated object.

```
Profile::find(1);
```

vs.

```
$profile->find(1);
```